# Avoiding multiple objects of same name in C++

Tags: c++

I am building a simple package manager for my new Linux distro ([check it out as soon as I finish](http://www.elephant-os.org)) and have run into a problem.  My `install()` and `remove()` functions need to access an unspecified amount of `Package` objects.  This is the install function.

```
void install(int argc, char *argv[]) throw()
{
        for (int i = 2; i <= argc; i++)
        {
                Package p(argv[i]);
                p.fetch();
                cout << "Package " << p.getRef() << " retrieved succesfully from server.\n";
                p.install();
                cout << "Package " << p.getRef() << " installed succesfully.\n";
        }
}
```

I suspect this code isn't entirely kosher; this would result in several objects named `p` which would probably cause a compilation and/or runtime error.  What I'm looking for is either a way to change the name `p` in each iteration of the loop or delete `p` after one iteration so I will be free to create another object of that name.

Comment: You need to go read a good book on C++, especially about scoping rules. The variable `p` is declared locally inside the loop, every time the loop iterates a new and unique object is created.

Comment: **Good Books:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no discernible problem with your code nor will there be any issue with multiple objects. The variable `p` has automatic [storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) and is destroyed when it goes out of [scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope). When this means is that at the end of each iteration of the `for` loop `p` is destroyed and no longer exists.

Comment: I thought the object just stayed in existence throughout the loop.  I didn't realize that the content was destroyed in each iteration.

Comment: No. Because it has automatic storage duration its lifetime is limited to the _scope_ it is defined in. In this case the lifetime of `p` is defined by the _compound statement_ following the `for` statement.